# Can plant fruit and seeds be albino like animals?

Tags: genetics, botany

There are numerous examples of [albino animals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albinism_in_biology), including snakes, birds, fish, mammals---humans too. Apparently this comes from some a genetic defect that results in lack of pigment.

What about plants? Obviously a lack of chloraphyl would be fatal for a plant, so I'm imagining **the seed or fruit being white**. Does this exist in nature?

**Edit:** I'm thinking of fruit/seeds that are not normally white.

Note the wiki page I cited has only 2 paragraphs on this:

> In plants, albinism is characterised by partial or complete loss of chlorophyll pigments and incomplete differentiation of chloroplast membranes. Albinism in plants interferes with photosynthesis, which can reduce survivability.[4] Some plant variations may have white flowers or other parts. However, these plants are not totally devoid of chlorophyll. Terms associated with this phenomenon are "hypochromia" and "albiflora".[5]

That last part seems what I'm interested in, but the cite is a dead link.

Later in the article:

> The primary function of pigments in plants is photosynthesis, which uses the green pigment chlorophyll along with several red and yellow pigments including porphyrins, carotenoids, anthocyanins and betalains.

No cite there and not much info anyway.

So are white seeds or fruit found in nature?

If you're curious, I originally thought of this as an alternative way of getting white chocolate from an albino cocoa bean, and maybe even a white coffee bean too.

Comment: Coffee beans are green before they are roasted; the brown color comes from the Maillard reaction (and possibly some caramelization), same thing that makes bread brown on the crust, and chocolate as well. Coffee or chocolate without the color wouldn't taste anything like normal. And white chocolate isn't really chocolate, it's a candy made with only the "butter" from cocoa beans which is really just a vegetable oil.

Comment: @BryanKrause Right that is why I wanted a "real" white chocolate, tho ofc who knows what it would taste like. I didn't know about the green coffee beans tho. Interesting.

Comment: White seeds: rice? White fruit: banana (not the peel of course)?

Comment: Great place for me to plug the super interesting story about  [albino redwoods](https://www.google.com/amp/www.mercurynews.com/2016/09/11/albino-redwoods-mystery-of-ghosts-of-the-forest-may-be-solved/amp/)

Comment: @WYSIWYG Was thinking more like seeds/fruit that are not normally white but have suffered an albino gene.

Comment: @DrZ214 What about the [classic finding](http://study.com/cimages/multimages/16/transposons_in_maize2.jpg) of transposition in maize kernels by Barbara McClintock? That is, of course, within the same organism. There are variegated leaves too. Some vegetables also show variegation. There are white eggplant varieties. Do any of these examples fit your query?

Comment: @WYSIWYG I supposed it's a question of what exactly is considered an albino gene as opposed to a "normal" gene responsible for white or yellowish-white that we would not consider defective. Corn, maybe, but yellow and white could be kinda a gray area. I have never heard of white eggplant so I think yes there, but OTOH squash is yellow and eggplant and squash are very similar. Interesting, tho, that all those examples are vegetables and not fruit.

Comment: @DrZ214 Eggplant is a fruit.

Comment: @WYSIWYG Is it really? Yikes, it is. And it's a berry too? I'm sorry but what a terrible thing to classify as a berry IMO. It's a good thing we have genetics to use instead of tastes.

Comment: Do flowers count? There are some species where part of the population is white, e.g. Frittellaria meleagris

Comment: @RHA As far as I can tell, yes those count.

Comment: Don't know whether it counts as albinism, but there are quite a few white fruits out there.  Off the top of my head, there are white pumpkins, white corn, white peaches, white carrots,..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When thinking of albinism in fruits, the only thing I could think of is strawberries. Yes, there can be albinism in strawberries! They are nearly always assocoated with excess nitrogen and are usually tasteless. According to a research by Lieten *et al*, their mineral composition also differes. Albino strawberries contain higher N:Ca and K:Ca ratio than normal fruits. Another study by Sharma *et al* shows that albino strawberries show less lipoxygenase activity. Also, Hwang *et al* and team found that presence of more than normal silicon also causes, among many other things, albinism.

[image: albino strawberries]

You can get more information [here](http://ucanr.edu/sites/sdim/Physical_and_Physiological_Disorders/Albino_Fruit/), [here](http://www.academia.edu/20951001/Fruit_calcium_content_and_lipoxygenase_activity_in_relation_to_albinism_disorder_in_strawberry), [here](http://agris.fao.org/agris-search/search.do?recordID=KR2007002490) and [here](http://www.actahort.org/books/348/348_57.htm). Obviously, there could be numerous other examples, but albino strawberries is all I could remember.

*PS* the exact genetic cause and mechanism of albinism in strawberries is not known yet. When searching online, I only found a study by [Plante *et al*](http://www.ishs.org/ishs-article/560_36) which suggests presence of mixoploid cells over a critical number which might have an effect on it.

Comment: That's neat! Can they be safely eaten? Do they taste bad? If it's only a nutrient problem that causes it, and not a gene, then there must be some technical definition that I don't know that might exclude them.

Comment: Most probably the exact cause is not known and must be genetic. Also, they are mostly tasteless, but not harmful.

Comment: Interesting, so it could be a genetic defect that causes them to take up too much wrong nutrients. BTW you should get +1 just for that new link to acadamia. I've never seen a in-html paged document that loads so fast plus word searchable with CTRL+F like normal. Everyone else does pdf.

Answer (score 4):

[Albinism is very rare in plants, because most plants can't survive long without photosynthesis](http://study.com/academy/lesson/albinism-in-plants-characteristics-causes.html). A notable exception is *Sequoia sempervirens*, an American tree that seems to be able to survive as albino through parasitism. [Source](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albinism#in_plants)

[image: img 1]

In some plant species with coloured flowers, some specimens are white. A good example is [*Fritillaria meleagris*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fritillaria_meleagris), for a photo of the white flowers see the [Dutch wikipedia page](https://nl.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kievitsbloem).

[image: img 2]

Another example of white flowers is [*Corydalis cava.*](http://www.eifelnatur.de/Niederl%E4ndisch/Seiten/Corydalis%20cava.html)

[image: img 3]

However, this is not true albinism, because green parts of the plant are not affected.

Comment: Good answer, +1! I've added photos and corrected links, feel free to roll back :)